# Optional chaining, but for a variable?

Tags: javascript

For something like the following:

```js
"use strict";
let a = 1;
console.log(eval(`
    a++; 
    let b=4;
`));
console.log(`a=${a}, b=${b}`);
// ReferenceError: b is not defined
```

Is it possible to do something where it prints `undefined` or something if the variable is not there instead of throwing an error? Something conceptually like:

```
console.log(`a=${a}, b=$?.{b}`)
```

Comment: For standalone identifiers, the only way to see if they exist is to check their `typeof`

Comment: the problem is not that its undefined, its that its not defined. As in, not declared anywhere

Comment: @CertainPerformance so maybe this would be the shortest way to do it? ```console.log(`a=${a}, b=${typeof b === 'undefined' ? 'none' : b}`);``` ?

Comment: That's right, with the conditional operator

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder has to contain an expression and there doesn't seem to bean idiomatic way of using an undefined variable (likely due to parsing error) so I would go with a getter instead of using a raw variable.

For example before accessing `b` you can write

```
let getB = function () {
    return (typeof b !== "undefined")? b :undefined;
}
```

Then in the template literal you can write `${getB}`.

Comment: could you show how that would work or what you mean? If it's a getter, wouldn't you have to pass the variable itself to it which would produce a referenceerror ?

Comment: @David542 Getters don't take arguments. In the getter function you can do any type of type checking logic and are able to return a string or a value like null.

Comment: ok, do you want to show that in your answer with some code instead of just your single sentence and I can go ahead and accept your answer?